# Angular js - call a route without view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers, route-provider

I'm trying calling the `/auth/logout` url to get redirected after session is deleted:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/auth/logout',{
        controller:'AuthLogout'
        //templateUrl: not needed

    })
})
.controller('AuthLogout', ['$window','$location', function ($window,$location) {
    $window.localStorage.removeItem('user_username');
    $window.localStorage.removeItem('user_id');
    $window.localStorage.removeItem('user_session_token');
    $location.path('/');
}]);
```

I actually don't need a view for AuthLogout controller but if I do not specify the `templateUrl` in routeProvider I can't get this to work, while if I specify a `templateUrl` it works.

How can I call the url/controller without to having to load a view??

Comment: Try template:'' a little tricky but it should work ^^

Comment: i get a an infinite loop and the browser crashes with this :O

Comment: this is strange in the when block you can use or template or templateUrl so the infinite loop I think it's not relate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do :

```
.when('/auth/logout', {
    controller: function(){
         //do staff
    }
})
```

btw may be there is something wrong in your code
because template works and you could exploit it in
the same way

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a resolve handler according to the post https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1838

Checkout this quick example and notice the alert statement in resolve.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wk7WD/34/

```
.when('/detail/:id/', {
    resolve: {
        load: function ($route, dataService) {
            alert("hello");
            //Your statements instead of all this which I found in an example
            return dataService.load($route.current.params.id);
        }
    }
})
```

Instead of the alert you can have your own statements

Answer (score 1):

use `redirectTo`

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/auth/logout',{
        redirectTo:'/'

    })
});
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: trying it out not sure it helps cause i need to run the AthLogout controller and then redirect...